# Trying to use Resources.Load() on unity and I get an error CS0234

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Assets/Resources/Game/Game.cs(15,53): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Load' does not exist in the namespace`Resources'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

using InControl;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour {

private float _originalTimeScale;
private float _slowMoTimeScale;  //slow motion time scale
private float _fastMoTimeScale;  //fast motion time scale
private float factor = 4f;      //factor to increase or decrease the timescale by

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    GameObject playerPreFab = Resources.Load("Ethan", GameObject);
...
```

Comment: Please paste your code where the error occurs.

Comment: @Inisheer i have editted my question with the code.. GameObject playerPreFab = Resources.Load("Ethan", GameObject); is the error line

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some syntax of Resources.Load. It should be:

```
(GameObject)Resources.Load("Ethan", typeof(GameObject))
```

in your case.